# How could a file be corrupted?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent

My understanding is that the hash list in info should protect the integrity of the downloaded files, but could the files be corrupted? Taken from [Torrent Poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_poisoning)

> A malicious user pollutes the file by converting it into another format that is indistinguishable from uncorrupted files (e.g. it may have similar or same metadata).

How could a file be polluted and still pass the integrity test?

Thanks

Comment: The original file was already corrupted/invalid/fake when the torrent was made. BitTorrent is correctly reproducing incorrect data. This isn't an attack on BitTorrent, it's just someone lying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making an assumption here, but I think you are confusing the terms "data" and "metadata". If a file is corrupted, the data itself is a mess, but the information that a system uses to identify that file could be intact according to the system. For example, I present you a glass full of a clear liquid and tell you it's water. From a glance you can see that it is entirely possible it is water, and so you drink it only to find out it is actually vodka. You are the system, and it is only when you actually "used" the glass of liquid that you found out that its contents are not what you expected.

Now give that glass to an expert on verifying that glasses of clear liquid are filled with water, and they will say to you, "No, this is not what it is meant to be". The "expert" is your checksum comparison tool. A checksum will be generated from the entire file, not just the metadata.

Comment: Doesn't 'Decoy Insertion' refer to the corruption of the content rather than the metadata? By your analogy, it tries to fool the "expert" that the vodka is water. The article reads "Decoy insertion (or content pollution) is a method by which corrupted versions of a particular file are inserted into the network. This deters users from finding an uncorrupted version and also increases distribution of the corrupted file."

Comment: No it tries to fool you that the vodka is water. The expert analyses every part of the glass and contents and compares it to what a glass of water should be (ie comparing two checksums). If they don't match, then the files are not identical.

Comment: Decoy insertion, from that definition, is simply attempting to distribute a false version of a file to the point where users trust the false version. For example, a JPEG viewer app takes in JPEGs. If you give it a JPEG file that looks like a JPEG, except it contains code for a virus, the JPEG viewer will still accept the file, but will actually run the malicious code. Doing a checksum comparison on the file will fail, as the order of bytes in the whole file is different to what it should be, which will generate a different checksum.

Comment: This is exactly the issue checksums aim to avoid. If we lived in a perfect world and every single person did checksum comparisons on every file they used, then decoy insertion would never work. (Then again in a perfect world, malicious acts wouldn't exist)

Comment: BitTorrent does ensure the integrity of contents, not just metadata, fwiw. (I don't entirely follow so I'm not sure if this is worth stating)

Comment: @JeremyBanks I am speaking generally here, not specifically about P2P or torrenting.